# runfile('C:/Users/Admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/.spyder-py3')

Tags: python, data-science, spyder, python-decorators

I try to run a script, but I am facing this type of error. How can I fix that error?
I can't find the reason.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Admin/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/.spyder-py3')
Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The first line you posted above is not an error. It's just the command to run your code. The second one shouldn't be there unless you're using an old Spyder version. Please update to our latest version to see that one removed.

Answer (score 0):

To remove it: Preferences ‣ Python interpreter ‣ User Module Reloader (UMR)

For more info: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/ipythonconsole.html